# Django sessions abandoned in first tab when clicking link in second

Tags: django, session, cookies

Don't know if this is specific to Django, but my site is the only one I've experienced this with, and I don't think I'm doing anything special with session data (just using the old-school database backend).

When a user logs in (in tab A) and opens a new tab (tab B) on the same domain, the cookie carries over to the second tab. However, if the user clicks a link in tab B, then either refreshes tab A or clicks a link in that tab, he's instantly logged out.

I've been Googling around the issue for ages but have had no luck, so would really appreciate anyone's help. Apologies if this is a really fundamental thing.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'bambu.sites.middleware.DomainRedirectMiddleware',
    'nymbol.utils.middleware.RequireHTTPSMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'maintenancemode.middleware.MaintenanceModeMiddleware',
    'bambu.analytics.middleware.AnalyticsMiddleware',
    'bambu.enqueue.middleware.EnqueueMiddleware',
    'bambu.minidetect.middleware.MiniDetectMiddleware',
    'nymbol.utils.middleware.UserPlanMiddleware',
    'nymbol.manager.middleware.APILegacyMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware'
)
```

- `bambu.sites.middleware.DomainRedirectMiddleware` redirects visitors to the correct domain, as the site has a number of alias domains
- `nymbol.utils.middleware.RequireHTTPSMiddleware` redirects users of certain URLs to SSL versions of the same)
- `maintenancemode.middleware.MaintenanceModeMiddleware` displays a 503 message when the site is being deployed after a commit and push
- `bambu.analytics.middleware.AnalyticsMiddleware` enqueues analytics JavaScript across requests
- `bambu.enqueue.middleware.EnqueueMiddleware` allows views and template tags to enqueue CSS and JavaScript
- `bambu.minidetect.middleware.MiniDetectMiddleware` detects whether a browser is mobile or not
- `nymbol.utils.middleware.UserPlanMiddleware` stores the payment plan the user is currently on in the `request` object (as this governs site-wide permissions)
- `nymbol.manager.middleware.APILegacyMiddleware` changes a URL pattern in one particular URL to another (absolutely no bearing in this issue)

Comment: That's certainly not a common Django issue. Could it be related to a specific link that you click in tab B that deletes cookies? Have you tried if the issue persist when using a different browser? Can you post what middleware you're using (`MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in your settings file)?

Comment: Thanks @knbk; added details above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue I was having had nothing to do with Django, but was instead due to some insecure image URLs being delivered over TLS (SSL basically).

This is probably a bad explanation of the issue, but it seemed that when the browser - Chrome or Firefox - detected an http:// URL being referenced from a secure URL, it abandoned the session so the next time I hit refresh or clicked another link, I'd be taken to the login page as my cookie would no longer be valid.

As I say, probably not exactly how it's going down, but that's very much the practical upshot, and correcting those URLs (which is of course best-practice anyway) sorted the issue completely.